# Copying folders in Windows

Tags: windows, command-line

I have the following folders on a Windows machine

```
C:\FolderToCopy

C:\Dest
```

Both folders are empty.

I want to execute a copy operation from a command prompt so that I have this in the end:

```
C:\FolderToCopy

C:\Dest\FolderToCopy
```

In other words, I want to copy FolderToCopy so that it is now in the C:\Dest folder.

I know this should be easy - I do this often enough from the UI - but nothing I try seems to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
robocopy C:\FolderToCopy\ C:\Dest\FolderToCopy /E
```

Comment: That did the trick. Good ol' robocopy!

Answer (score 2):

```
XCOPY /S /Y C:\FolderToCopy C:\Dest\
```

The last slash is important.

Comment: I tried this (even with the last slash) but it didn't work.

Comment: If you want to use XCOPY in this concrete case, you must add the `/E` switch to copy also empty folders.

Answer (score 0):

`copy C:\FolderToCopy\*.* C:\Dest\FolderToCopy`

Comment: No joy with this, either.